# Identical Spark Cluster is much slower on new Machine

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I used to develop and run a Pyspark Script on a RedHat7 Machine. I had only 1 Masternode and 1 Worker Node with 500 GB of RAM and 6 Executors (5 cores each) both running on that Machine. Running the current version of the script on some constant test-data took approx. 90 Minutes and life was good.

Then my company decided that i should use a different Machine: Redhat9, 750GB RAM, 36 CPUs.
All the data was cloned from the Redhat7 Machine to the Redhat9 Machine, so it is for sure the same Spark version and Configuration as well as the exact same Code and test-Data. Only difference is that i have more RAM at my disposal now and added 1 more Executor due to the additional Cores. So if anything, I expected a slightly faster result.
To my surprise however, running the script on the new Machine takes roughly 3x as long (5h).

According to the UI, Garbage collection does not play a big role in the workload (on both environments) and the Network should also not be a factor since i am loading parquet files from local and dont communicate with any Databases or other Worker Nodes or Machines. In the UI I can also see that all Spark Cores are being used and the RAM is allocated correctly. Therefore I assume it has to be some Linux configuration? Or the RAM is not being used efficiently?

I did already some research and made sure the following things are given:

- Disabled swappiness
- Disabled THP
- Local disk configured without RAID and with noatime option

One difference i noticed between the 2 environments is that while the first/faster one created huge amounts of tmp files (~700GB), the Redhat9 Machine doesnt seem to do that. It only creates 2-50GB.
Moreover, the Redhat9 Machine is more restrictive and has higher security standards in general. But since i dont communicate with other entities i am not sure how big of a role this can play.
We also upgraded the python and java versions from 3.6 to 3.9 and java 11 to java 17, when we were moving from the old to the new machine.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the cause of these performance issues?